# How to assign class to invalid Symfony 2 form field, rendered with Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Lets assume that few fields values of my form, build on **Symfony 2** and rendered with **Twig** are not valid and I received validation errors. I want not only to see this errors, but also assign special class to each invalid field.

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="error">
```

How can I do that? As I understand, there is need to redeclare my form template. Is there any working example how to assign attributes in case of concrete field validation failure.

All I found now, is that I need to set this class in form template:

```
{% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ (errors|length > 0 ? ' error' : '') }) %}
```

But what I don't understand is how to specify exact field? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<div class="input{{ form_errors(form.expiry) == '' ? '' : 'error' }}">
    {{ form_widget(form.expiry) }}
</label>
```

You could also do

```
{{ form_widget(form.expiry, {'attr': {'class': form_errors(form.expiry) == '' ? '' : 'error'}}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

for showing your form, I am quite sure you can not accomplish what you want, or at least I am not aware of the possiblity.

If you use something like this

```
{{ form_row(form.task) }}
{{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}
```

I am still quite sure you can not get what you want.

My solution for what you need would be to make something like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div>
        {{ form_label(form.task) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.task) }}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ form_label(form.dueDate) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.dueDate) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.dueDate) }}
    </div>

<input type="submit" />

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and to simply get information about validation errors from form object and then to replace {{ form_widget(form.task) }} with something like this

```
{{ form_widget(form.task, {'attr': {'class': 'error'}}) }}
```

in case that field task failed the validation.

Even more slow and time consuming solution would be to make small twig files that each and every one would actualy represent "your" design for view of each form field and then to call those "little twigs" with an argument which would again come from form object which contains those data about bad validation.

You can read more about form rendering where you actualy make your own form field designs here

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html